# Java Scanner does not ignore new lines (\n)

Tags: java, hashmap

I know that by default, the Scanner skips over whitespaces and newlines. 
There is something wrong with my code because my Scanner does not ignore "\n".

For example: the input is "this is\na test." and the desired output should be ""this is a test."

this is what I did so far:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String token = scan.nextLine();
String[] output = token.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    if (hashmap.containsKey(output[i])) {
        output[i] = hashmap.get(output[i]);
    }
    System.out.print(output[i]);
    if (i != output.length - 1) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```

Comment: Scanner most definitely does not ignore whitespace or newlines. Those are used as delimiters for the default Scanner, and in particular new lines are the delimiter used when calling `Scanner#nextLine()`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels explains it pretty well. You are confused with Scanner methods such as `nextInt`, which do ignore new lines and white spaces. `nextLine` specifically using new lines to separate its returns.

Comment: I tried to use scan.useDelimiter("\n"), but without success. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course this will fail. You explicitly said it should stop reading on an `\n`, but this isn't what you want. So define an own delimiter, list `"#"` and write `"this is\na test.#"`

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` ignores the specified delimiter (as optionally set by `useDelimiter()`), and reads to the end of the current line.

Since input is two lines:

```
this is
a test.
```

only the first line (`this is`) is returned.

You then split that on whitespace, so `output` will contain `[this, is]`.

Since you never use the scanner again, the second line (`a test.`) will never be read.

In essence, your title is right on point: *Java Scanner does not ignore new lines (\n)*
It specifically processed the newline when you called `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a `Scanner` to do this

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String result = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Or if you really want to use a `Scanner` this should also work

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Spliterator<String> si = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(scanner, Spliterator.ORDERED);
        String result = StreamSupport.stream(si, false).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```